# Where should I put my take profit in this crypto trade?

Tags: trading, cryptocurrency

Let's say we want to buy BTC at price 45000.00 USDT (and we have $15 to buy BTC). The commission is 0.1%. Since we will pay for a commission, so What will be our break-even point for that trade?

I want to set my take-profit based on this point.
I have gotten  to this formula based on some calculations:

```
break-even-point = buy-price/(1 - 0.1%)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you pay a commission selling too wouldn't your break even point be:
price bought x .002 = Break even 45090 USDT

Comment: Commission each way is 0.1%, not 1% as in this calculation

Comment: commission was changed after I answered, corrected